# ENOENT errors when running npm inside vagrant shell provision

Tags: vagrant, npm

1. Have a project with the following `package.json` file:

   ```
   {
       "name": "requirejs-library-skeleton",
       "description": "RequireJS skeleton for modern JS libraries.",
       "version": "0.2.0",
       "homepage": "http://github.com/tkellen/requirejs-library-skeleton",
       "author": "Tyler Kellen",
       "engines": {
           "node": ">=0.6.0"
       },
       "scripts": {
           "test": "grunt test"
       },
       "devDependencies": {
           "grunt": "~0.4",
           "grunt-contrib-watch": "*",
           "grunt-contrib-less": "~0.6.1",
           "grunt-contrib-requirejs": "~0.3.2",
           "grunt-contrib-jasmine": "~0.4.0",
           "grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs": "*",
           "grunt-contrib-connect": "~0.1.0",
           "grunt-file-creator": "*",
           "clean-pattern": "*",
           "grunt-concat-css": "*",

           "grunt-phpcs": "*",
           "grunt-phplint": "*",
           "grunt-phpunit": "*",
           "grunt-exec": "*"
       }
   }
   ```
2. Have the following `Vagrantfile` config:

   ```
   Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

     config.vm.box = "precise32"
     config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box"

     config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "bootstrap/bootstrap.sh"

   # ... other stuff like opening ports ...

   end
   ```
3. `bootstrap.sh` is most interesting and looks like this:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env bash

   # Installing prequisites for adding nodejs repository
   apt-get update
   apt-get install -y python-software-properties python g++ make

   # Adding Nodejs specific repository
   add-apt-repository -y ppa:chris-lea/node.js

   # Installing other software
   # ... apt-get invocations ...

   # Installing grunt harness
   npm install -g grunt-cli

   # Other preparation tasks
   # ... setting up DB, runtime directories, generating configs, etc.

   # Moving to codebase root now
   cd /vagrant

   # Disguising ourselves as normal user (hack 1)
   su vagrant

   # Cleaning the NPM cache (hack 2)
   npm cache clean

   # Installing nodejs prequisites
   npm install

   # Rebuilding codebase (I have to run it after EVERY change in configuration, CSS and/or JS files).
   grunt

   # Other post-deploy application-specific things
   # ...

   echo "All should be done\n";
   ```
4. At the `npm install` invocation it fails miserably with the following random errors:

   ```
   npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash/-/lodash-1.0.1.tgz                                                                                                         
   npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/vagrant/node_modules/grunt-contrib-jasmine/node_modules/grunt-lib-phantomjs/node_modules/phantomjs/node_modules/adm-zip/.travis.yml'      
   npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:                                                                                                                    
   npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>                                                                                                                        
   npm ERR! or email it to:                                                                                                                                                  
   npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>                                                                                                                                      

   npm ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-23-generic-pae                                                                                                                                
   npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"                                                                                                                 
   npm ERR! cwd /vagrant                                                                                                                                                     
   npm ERR! node -v v0.10.22                                                                                                                                                 
   npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.14                                                                                                                                                    
   npm ERR! path /vagrant/node_modules/grunt-contrib-jasmine/node_modules/grunt-lib-phantomjs/node_modules/phantomjs/node_modules/adm-zip/.travis.yml                        
   npm ERR! fstream_path /vagrant/node_modules/grunt-contrib-jasmine/node_modules/grunt-lib-phantomjs/node_modules/phantomjs/node_modules/adm-zip/.travis.yml                
   npm ERR! fstream_type File                                                                                                                                                
   npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter                                                                                                                                         
   npm ERR! code ENOENT                                                                                                                                                      
   npm ERR! errno 34                                                                                                                                                         
   npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26                                                                                
   npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)                                                                                                                   
   npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/vagrant/node_modules/grunt-contrib-jasmine/node_modules/grunt-lib-phantomjs/node_modules/phantomjs/node_modules/mkdirp/test/mkdirp.js'    
   npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:                                                                                                                    
   npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>                                                                                                                        
   npm ERR! or email it to:                                                                                                                                                  
   npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>                                                                                                                                      

   npm ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-23-generic-pae                                                                                                                                
   npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"                                                                                                                 
   npm ERR! cwd /vagrant                                                                                                                                                     
   npm ERR! node -v v0.10.22                                                                                                                                                 
   npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.14                                                                                                                                                    
   npm ERR! path /vagrant/node_modules/grunt-contrib-jasmine/node_modules/grunt-lib-phantomjs/node_modules/phantomjs/node_modules/mkdirp/test/mkdirp.js                      
   npm ERR! fstream_path /vagrant/node_modules/grunt-contrib-jasmine/node_modules/grunt-lib-phantomjs/node_modules/phantomjs/node_modules/mkdirp/test/mkdirp.js              
   npm ERR! fstream_type File                                                                                                                                                
   npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter                                                                                                                                         
   npm ERR! code ENOENT                                                                                                                                                      
   npm ERR! errno 34                                                                                                                                                         
   npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26                                                                                
   npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)                                                                                                                   
   npm ERR! EEXIST, mkdir '/vagrant/node_modules/grunt-contrib-jasmine/node_modules/grunt-lib-phantomjs/node_modules/phantomjs/node_modules/npmconf/test'                    
   File exists: /vagrant/node_modules/grunt-contrib-jasmine/node_modules/grunt-lib-phantomjs/node_modules/phantomjs/node_modules/npmconf/test                                
   Move it away, and try again.                                                                                                                                              

   npm ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-23-generic-pae                                                                                                                                
   npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"                                                                                                                 
   npm ERR! cwd /vagrant                                                                                                                                                     
   npm ERR! node -v v0.10.22                                                                                                                                                 
   npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.14                                                                                                                                                    
   npm ERR! path /vagrant/node_modules/grunt-contrib-jasmine/node_modules/grunt-lib-phantomjs/node_modules/phantomjs/node_modules/npmconf/test                               
   npm ERR! fstream_path /vagrant/node_modules/grunt-contrib-jasmine/node_modules/grunt-lib-phantomjs/node_modules/phantomjs/node_modules/npmconf/test/builtin.js            
   npm ERR! fstream_type File                                                                                                                                                
   npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter                                                                                                                                         
   npm ERR! code EEXIST                                                                                                                                                      
   npm ERR! errno 47                                                                                                                                                         
   npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:171:23                                                                                
   npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:37:53                                                                                       
   npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)                                                                                                                   
   npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/vagrant/node_modules/grunt-contrib-jasmine/node_modules/grunt-lib-phantomjs/node_modules/phantomjs/node_modules/kew/test/context.js'      
   npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:                                                                                                                    
   npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>                                                                                                                        
   npm ERR! or email it to:                                                                                                                                                  
   npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>                                                                                                                                      

   npm ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-23-generic-pae                                                                                                                                
   npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"                                                                                                                 
   npm ERR! cwd /vagrant                                                                                                                                                     
   npm ERR! node -v v0.10.22                                                                                                                                                 
   npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.14                                                                                                                                                    
   npm ERR! path /vagrant/node_modules/grunt-contrib-jasmine/node_modules/grunt-lib-phantomjs/node_modules/phantomjs/node_modules/kew/test/context.js                        
   npm ERR! fstream_path /vagrant/node_modules/grunt-contrib-jasmine/node_modules/grunt-lib-phantomjs/node_modules/phantomjs/node_modules/kew/test/context.js                
   npm ERR! fstream_type File                                                                                                                                                
   npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter                                                                                                                                         
   npm ERR! code ENOENT                                                                                                                                                      
   npm ERR! errno 34                                                                                                                                                         
   npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26                                                                                
   npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)                                                                                                                   
   npm ERR! EEXIST, mkdir '/vagrant/node_modules/grunt-contrib-jasmine/node_modules/grunt-lib-phantomjs/node_modules/phantomjs/node_modules/ncp/test/fixtures/src'           
   File exists: /vagrant/node_modules/grunt-contrib-jasmine/node_modules/grunt-lib-phantomjs/node_modules/phantomjs/node_modules/ncp/test/fixtures/src                       
   Move it away, and try again.                                                                                                                                              

   npm ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-23-generic-pae                                                                                                                                
   npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"                                                                                                                 
   npm ERR! cwd /vagrant                                                                                                                                                     
   npm ERR! node -v v0.10.22                                                                                                                                                 
   npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.14                                                                                                                                                    
   npm ERR! path /vagrant/node_modules/grunt-contrib-jasmine/node_modules/grunt-lib-phantomjs/node_modules/phantomjs/node_modules/ncp/test/fixtures/src                      
   npm ERR! fstream_path /vagrant/node_modules/grunt-contrib-jasmine/node_modules/grunt-lib-phantomjs/node_modules/phantomjs/node_modules/ncp/test/fixtures/src/d            
   npm ERR! fstream_type File                                                                                                                                                
   npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter                                                                                                                                         
   npm ERR! code EEXIST                                                                                                                                                      
   npm ERR! errno 47                                                                                                                                                         
   npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:171:23                                                                                
   npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:37:53                                                                                       
   npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
   ```

What the heck is going on here?

**If I do the `vagrant ssh` and run `cd /vagrant; npm install` there npm runs without any problems!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I have found solution in here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/269727/npm-errors-when-installing-packages-on-windows-share

I just have to use `npm install --no-bin-links`.
Would be glad to have an answer **why**.

Comment: The reason specified in your link is that virtualbox did not allow symlinks in folders shared with the Windows host; however, I'm still getting errors even after allowing symlinks.